# Variable $file got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid

Tags: node.js, file-upload, graphql

I'm trying to upload a file to graphql server with postmen. But I'm getting this error(Variable $file got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid). Please help me to resolve this. I'm using type-graphql to build the API.

`operation: {"query":"mutation($file: Upload!) {\n  uploadFile(file: $file)\n}"}`

`map: {"0": ["variables.file"]}`

`0: file.png`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable "$file" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64658321/variable-file-got-invalid-value-upload-value-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `graphql-upload` and `apollo-server-express` you may have to set uploads to false on the `ApolloServer` configuration and then use `graphqlUploadExpress()` from `graphql-upload`.

For example:

```
 app = express();
 new ApolloServer({ schema, context, uploads: false });
 app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000, maxFiles: 10 }));
 server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

Comment: This resolves the problem but i cant get uploaded file's file size. I want to check file size, any suggestion about this? Thanks